# Can you get better performance from Heroku by bypassing the Cedar routing layer?

Tags: performance, web-applications, heroku, cloud

With the recent revelation that Heroku's 'intelligent routing mesh' is simply a [randomizing loadbalancer](http://rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics), I'm wondering if it would be possible to improve performance by using the Bamboo stack's routing ? I say this because I discovered the following from [a Heroku support article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords#heroku-behavior):

*On Heroku, specifically, sending application traffic to a static IP addresses is not supported. It causes that traffic to be routed through the Bamboo stack’s routing infrastructure and not the routing layer of the more performant Cedar stack (even for app’s whose runtime exists on the Cedar stack). Such applications lose the functional benefits of the streamlined Cedar routing stack and are subject to additional downtime*

Now, I'm curious to know if someone has tried benchmarking the Bamboo router vs the Cedar router ? As an aside, is the referenced document accurate (given that much of Heroku's [documentation is misleading/incorrect](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/16/routing_performance_update/)) ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Bamboo is not recommended, as the documentation you've found also states. The source of the latency mentioned in the blog post you reference is not the actual Heroku router; it's due to requests waiting in queues on the individual dynos. Mapping your domain to static IP addresses will not improve average response time for your app.

Comment: Given that:

* I get that Bamboo is not recommended, it appears to be deprecated and strongly discouraged. In practice it works and is therefor a possible option, which is why I was asking.
* The source of the latency is because the router can and probably will send multiple requests to a given dyno, while leaving others idle.

I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but without understanding why the Bamboo routing is practically worse it's hard to tell if it based on fact or opinion.